# Login form have some problems

Tags: livecode

I am beginner in Livecode. I got some code for log in. My problem is I want to convert the password to "*"  How i change the following code

```
local sUsername, sPassword

on openCard
put "johnsmith" into sUsername
put "pa55word" into sPassword
end openCard

on loginCheck
if field "username" is sUsername and field "password" is sPassword then
answer "Login Successful"
go to card "accessed"
else
answer "Details Incorrect. Please try again!"
end if
end loginCheck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is to use the keyDown message along with a custom property to store the clear text.  Place the following code in the password field's script:

```
on keyDown theKey
   -- RESTRICT THE ALLOWED KEYS TO SOME DEFINED CHARACTERS
   if theKey is not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" then exit keyDown
   put the hiddenText of me into temp
   put theKey after temp
   set the hiddenText of me to temp
   put "*" after me
end keyDown

on backspaceKey
   set the hiddenText of me to empty
   set the text of me to empty
end backspaceKey
```

The second line in the keyDown handler lets you limit the characters that are accepted for the password to a defined list (you could include special characters such as "#" and "_" and others if you wish). The backspaceKey handler is used to delete any entered characters and start over.

Note that you may want to handle special cases such when the enterKey and/or returnKeys are pressed, which often trigger the submission of a form.